# PHP: Echo function output in function-line, not line of function call

Tags: php, function, templates

I have a problem with my self-coded template system. The content is inserted by Include(). Now I need to add a meta redirect to one page. I know, meta redirect is not the safest way, but I need it because of it's delay possibility.

Now i'm looking for a way to influence the wrapping page (template) by the wrapped page (content).

So I thought a function can do this job.

```
<?php function test($testvar){
    echo $testvar;}
    ?>

<hr />

<?php
test("testtext");
?>
```

Of course the text echos in the line of the function call, not in the function line. Is there a way to make the function echo in the line of the function itself? In this case above the horizontal rule, not below?

Of course every other best pratice for this "template problem" ist welcome!

THX

EDIT:

```
    <html>
    <title>testpage</title>
    <? a_function_that_echos_a_metatag_for_redericetion($param){
echo $param;
}

?>
    <head>

    <body>
    <? include("test.php");
    INCLUDED script---->
a_function_that_echos_a_metatag_for_redericetion("\"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"...")
```

Comment: You want it to echo above the `<hr />` where you defined the function as well as below where you called the function?

Comment: _I know, meta redirect is not the safest way, but I need it because of it's delay possibility._ -- nothing wrong with this.

Comment: The call to echo will happen where ever the function is called, not where it is defined.

Comment: No, just above the hr.

Comment: Are you trying to create the whole page, then write the meta redirect? The meta redirect should wait until the page loads before beginning the time delay, so you shouldn't need to wait until the page is finished before writing that. Or is there some other reason you'd want to wait til the end and echo above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedural programming cannot have the logic you request.
If you want to add the meta redirect element before the page content, you HAVE to know that you are GOING to make this redirect before the <head> is closed.

Comment: A Common way to overcome this issue is to render the HTML only after the entire page has finished executing server-side code (similar to so-called 'output buffering')

Comment: I am going to suggest you go with this idea. I feel it is always better to have two stages of the script. One for all of the neccessary processing, then render everything to the screen. This allows you to make sure the page is good to go before writing anything to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the function echo in the line of the function
>   itself?

No. Functions are declarations and aren't executed until they are *called*.

If you wish to modify the request headers later down the page, then you'll need to employ [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). However, this approach will likely be overkill if only one page needs the special header consideration. It may be better to just detect the page via some parameter (such as `REQUEST_URI`) and insert the header conditionally from that.